# Querying posts by latitude and longitude to build a Google Maps with several markers

Tags: custom-field, terms, advanced-custom-fields, google-maps, geo-data

I have 4 different post types and 4 differey taxonomies Each term for each taxonomy stores a marker (url to a png icon). Each post has coordinates attached with [Advanced Custom Fields](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf/) and I'll probably use [Geo Data Store](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geo-data-store/) to optimise scalability.

- a) how would you ideally query for the posts which fall under a specified km radius by lat and lng with Wordpress? I'd like to avoid, if possible, direct db queries.
- b) I'm going to store coordinates in a different table with Geo Data Store. But how about markers? Is it a good idea to store the icon/marker url of each term in a meta field for these terms?
- c) in general, what do you think would be the best practice to approach the project outlined above? I'd like to avoid to use further plugins (except for ACF)

Thanks in advance for all your advices.

Comment: This is much too much for a single question & a especially for a single answer. You'll need to narrow it down. This currently sounds more like a "Line out my whole APP and give me TODO/taks list incl. all needed code" a.k.a. "Do this job for me".

Comment: Google has [a tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) that will give you the query you need for radius search.

Comment: kaiser sorry I didn't want to ask "write the code for me" I just wanted advices - I reckon it may be a bit generic, but the two specific questions in the end are: 1) how to query by radius; 2) is a good idea to store the marker in a term meta - if some moderator think it's still too generic it's ok they can delete the question sorry

Comment: It's not about deleting - just about bringing a focus to it, so a single answer is possible. Also "radius search" (as pointed out by @Milo) is off topic here and better asked/read up somewhere else. About the second answer: Yes this is ok, as I answered. Just make sure to rework your question to bring it on topic and make it short and readable.

Comment: very well, shortened :)

Answer (score 2):

To connect your meta fields with the "Geo Data Store"-Plugin, you simply take the name of the meta key/field and map it with the filter to the plugin.

```
add_filter( 'sc_geodatastore_meta_keys', 'wpse82502_lat_lng_metakey_mapping' );
function wpse82502_lat_lng_metakey_mapping( $keys )
{
    $keys[] = "your_meta_key_field_name";
    return $keys;
}
```

To get the data from PHP to JS, simply use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).